# ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/core error while run app

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, node-modules

ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/core

I create Ionic App and while I run it that gives the above error

my tsconfig look like below:

````
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": [
        "src/app/shared/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}```

error while running app
````

Answer (score 1):

mostly this kind of error happens if there is a problem in paths. correcting the paths fixed the above issue. or you can simply, if you have another project open that and u can open tsconfig.json then copy all data and paste that in your project error . solved
if you don't have another project create one then try to do above.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. I didn't need to touch my packages at all. My tsconfig.json was corrupt for some weird reason. I restored it, removed the node_modules, deleted package-lock.json and run npm run install.